# X.org loaded intel driver, disables everything else

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am trying to get my laptop to use my Nvidia Geforce GT 640M GPU. When I look at the "Software & updates > Additional Drivers" panel it is completely empty. It looks like the problem is here:

```
ubuntu-drivers debug
=== log messages from detection ===
DEBUG:root:X.org log reports loaded intel driver, disabling driver nvidia-173 for hybrid system
DEBUG:root:X.org log reports loaded intel driver, disabling driver nvidia-173-updates for hybrid system
DEBUG:root:X.org log reports loaded intel driver, disabling driver nvidia-304 for hybrid system
...
```

The output of lshw (in case that helps):

```
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 09
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:42 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:a0000000(size=536870912)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GK107 [GeForce GT 640M]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: a1
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
            resources: irq:16 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:48 memory:d2000000-d23fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

How do I force X to ignore the Intel graphics and use the Nvida GPU instead?

Comment: What are the contents of xorg.conf?

Comment: Err, I don't think Ubuntu has had one by default for a while now. I don't see one lurking in /etc...

Comment: Ok, I was just checking, occasionally drivers try to generate their own and break things with them.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: I have the same problem, I logged a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310568